# Calling an android method from Unity3D with a JAR plugin

Tags: c#, android, eclipse, unity-game-engine, social-networking

I am developing a game with Unity only for Android platform and I am requiring to share content of my game through an intent so I have implemented a JAR plugin according to several tutorials with this code:

```
package a.b.c;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity;

public class UnityBridge extends UnityPlayerActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void callShareIntent() {
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        startActivity(shareIntent);
    }
}
```

The JAR is located at Assets/Plugins/Android with an AndroidManifest file which override the file created by unity, this is its code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto" package="a.b.c"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:debuggable="false">
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|fontScale">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="false" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".UnityBridge"></activity>
    </application>
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x20000" />
</manifest>
```

I just copied the manifest created by Unity and added this line:

```
<activity android:name=".UnityBridge"></activity>
```

... as you can see.

In the other hand, I have created a C# file in order to launch the share method of the plugin, this is its code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BotonCompartir : MonoBehaviour {

    AndroidJavaClass androidClass;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android) {
            AndroidJNI.AttachCurrentThread ();
            androidClass = new AndroidJavaClass ("a.b.c.UnityBridge");
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0) && Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android) {
            androidClass.Call("callShareIntent");
        }
    }
}
```

... and I have attached it to a gameobject.

When I deploy the apk to an android device nothing happens, so What am I doing wrong? Any other suggestion?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have extend UnityPlayerActivity in your UnityBridge, you have to set it as a main activity in you AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<activity
    android:name=".UnityBridge"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```